# Issue with iOS low memory crash but using very low memory - checked with instruments

Tags: ios, memory-management

I have a sample App that works fine on the simulator, but crashes on the device. I get the following output on the console from Organizer. It crashes within a short time.

Using instruments, memory leak, I see that the memory usage is about 2-3 mb. Using memory allocations, I see around 8-9mb for memory allocations and nothing in VM tracker.

The console output is given below. Can anyone kindly suggest what to do?

```
    pr 26 11:46:37 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Warning>: Memory level is not normal (2). Delaying auto-relaunch of 'com.apple.mobilemail' for 30 seconds.
    Apr 26 11:46:44 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Warning>: No valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application 'SampleApp': (null). Notifications will not be delivered.
    Apr 26 11:46:44 unknown SampleApp[14834] <Warning>: unique id: //someID
    Apr 26 11:46:45 unknown SampleApp[14834] <Warning>: Failed to get token, error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application" UserInfo=0x2322ae {NSLocalizedDescription=no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application}
    Apr 26 11:46:46 unknown UserEventAgent[12] <Notice>: jetsam: kernel termination snapshot being created
    Apr 26 11:46:46 unknown com.apple.debugserver-64[14833] <Warning>: 1 [39f1/1303]: error: ::read ( 4, 0x2ff389d4, 1024 ) => -1 err = Bad file descriptor (0x00000009)
    Apr 26 11:46:46 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (com.apple.atc) Exited: Killed: 9
    Apr 26 11:46:46 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.fun.SampleApp.ios[0x2344]) Bug: launchd_core_logic.c:3730 (25147):3
    Apr 26 11:46:46 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.fun.SampleApp.ios[0x2344]) Assuming job exited: <rdar://problem/5020256>: 10: No child processes
    Apr 26 11:46:46 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.fun.SampleApp.ios[0x2344]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11
    Apr 26 11:46:46 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (com.apple.mediaserverd) Exited: Killed: 9
    Apr 26 11:46:46 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (com.apple.ubd) Exited: Killed: 9
    Apr 26 11:46:47 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[14836] Builtin profile: mediaserverd (sandbox)
    Apr 26 11:46:48 unknown lockdownd[21] <Error>: 2ffd4000 _receive_message: walk away - non-SSL 1
    Apr 26 11:46:48 unknown com.apple.mobile.lockdown[21] <Notice>: receive secure message timeout!
    Apr 26 11:46:48 unknown ReportCrash[14838] <Error>: Saved crashreport to /Library/Logs/CrashReporter/LowMemory-2012-04-26-114648.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 0 egid: 0
    Apr 26 11:46:49 unknown mediaserverd[14836] <Error>: 11:46:49.618590 com.apple.AVConference: /SourceCache/GameKitServices/GameKitServices-344.3/AVConference.subproj/Sources/AVConferenceServer.m:1862: AVConferenceServerStart aborting - device doesn't support conferencing
    Apr 26 11:46:49 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Warning>: Application 'SampleApp' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11
    Apr 26 11:46:52 unknown atc[14835] <Warning>: Error: Connection invalid
    Apr 26 11:46:53 unknown wifid[27] <Error>: WiFi:[357158813.1212122]: Client itunesstored is background application
    Apr 26 11:47:07 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Warning>: Memory level is not normal (2). Delaying auto-relaunch of 'com.apple.mobilemail' for 30 seconds.
    Apr 26 11:47:37 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Warning>: Memory level is not normal (2). Delaying auto-relaunch of 'com.apple.mobilemail' for 30 seconds.
    Apr 26 11:48:07 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Warning>: Memory level is not normal (2). Delaying auto-relaunch of 'com.apple.mobilemail' for 30 seconds.
    Apr 26 11:48:37 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Warning>: Memory level is not normal (2). Delaying auto-relaunch of 'com.apple.mobilemail' for 30 seconds.
    Apr 26 11:48:49 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Notice>: Posting 'com.apple.iokit.hid.displayStatus' notifyState=0
```

Comment: ok, so tried profiling on the simulator. seems that it does require, at some point, 70-80mb before getting back to 2-3 mb.... maybe thats the problem...

Comment: also, no dirty or resident using VM Tracker.

Answer (score 0):

ok, so it seems like everything was fine, I just needed to delete the app from the iPad and reinstall it... pretty weird... !!!